I want to find Pair Address manually by code in python
Hello let's say this token:
TokenA = 8cG1JC9fCwpdZ9ofsEfhKJhBgKhzYCqnbbaKdC9RYw53
Native Token SOL = So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112
pair id on raydium i don't want to use raydium sdk to find it's pair id.
that's the pair id: CJFBHkfwrLzHnErY5sKKMtFnjdrEPwzvuVPJqFA6MqXX
i want to find by python or node js in the code but avoid using raydium sdk is there a way?

You can probably do it if you copy code from the raydium SDK, but otherwise you'll need some of the help from their library.
